# How to remove newline breaks in fields in Unix file without using perl

Tags: bash, perl, unix

I have a file which has newline breaks in one of the fields.
eg: 
See third line :

```
"A"|"USD"|"123"|"AIRPROMOTION"|"EXPIRE"

"B"|"USD"|"456"|"AIRPROMOTION"|"EXPIRE"

"C"|"USD"|"789
"|"AIRPROMOTION"|"EXPIRE"
```

I tried the command `perl -p00e 's/\n"|//g'` which worked just fine for a small file.But my file is huge (~100MB) and it gives 'Segmentation fault' error.
What are the other options?

Comment: what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Are you sure the command worked? No backslash before the vertical bar? Newline and double quote removed? What output do you expect?

Comment: use sed like the answer I've given, should be very fast

Answer (score 1):

The reason of segmentation fault is your are enable the slurp mode. Don't do that. Instead read the file line by line.

Try this

```
perl -lne 'my $nxt_line = <>;($nxt_line=~m/^"\|"/)?print "$_$nxt_line":print "$_"' file.txt
```

In above script `$nxt_line` will store the next line of the file.. Then make the pattern match for to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Should work like a charm!

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n"/"/g' input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use Notepad++ Replace function (\r\n\r\n and replace it with \r\n).

If you haven't it, you can download Notepad++ for free and is very useful application and has many uses.

At the View menu select Show Symbol and check on Show All Characters.

Press Cntrl+H or click on Search Menu and select Replace... option
Type in \r\n\r\n at Find what: 
Type in \r\n at Replace it with
Click on Replace All button.

PS: The Text you have supplied is not just LF, it is CRLF which is \r\n. You can try your method. Remember you want to just replace CRLFCRLF with one CRLF, otherwise you will loose all your CRLF and all your text will appear in one line.

Comment: Also, using Notepad++ to replace a file that huge wouldn't be recommended.

Comment: Also, your suggestion is not an answer to the OP's question.